# Silverlight rises an exception when hosted in MVC web page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight, exception

I have a silverlight project that works perfectly when I run it independently (i.e. run instance), but when I run it from my MVC website it rises an exception that says

```
Unhandled Error in Silverlight 2 Application
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at TakingMyPicture.MainPage..ctor()
   at TakingMyPicture.App.Application_Startup(Object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
   at MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(UInt32 typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)
   at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName, UInt32 flags)
```

Comment: Evidently something in your `MainPage` constructor is `null` and your code isn't checking whether it is null before attempting to use it.  Without the code of this constructor we can't really help you any more.

Comment: Can you provide some code of Application_Startup event?